# automatic onload pop-up without using the onload attribute in body tag

Tags: javascript, popup

Could you please give some links? When i google all spam sites come up!

Comment: I am glad pop up blockers block these.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `load` event on the `window` object:

DOM0 style:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("But please don't.");
};
```

Or using DOM2 methods:

```
if (window.addEventListener) { // DOM2 standard
    window.addEventListener('load', handler, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) { // Fallback for older IE versions
    window.attachEvent('onload', handler);
}
function handler() {
    alert("But again, please don't.");
}
```

As they say over at http://pastie.org, please use this information in your quest to save humanity, not your evil plots to take over the world.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear whether you just don't want to use the onload attribute, just not on the body element, or if you don't want to use the onload event at all.

T.J. Crowders answer gives some good examples for using event listeners, which is the best way to do it.

If for some reason you don't want to use the onload event at all, you could put a script tag in the HTML just before the  tag, with an alert inside it. You shouldn't do that for anything in production though... and it's not going to do the exact same thing as body.onload...

Answer (score 0):

I got the code!

I am copy pasting the exact code which worked......

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="http://dinhquanghuy.110mb.com/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    centerPopup();
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;  
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;  
    var windowscrolltop = document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
    var windowscrollleft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    var toppos = windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2+windowscrolltop;
    var leftpos = windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2+windowscrollleft;
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": toppos,
        "left": leftpos
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.cookie("anewsletter") != 1) {    

        //load popup
        setTimeout("loadPopup()",5000);    
    }        
    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
        $.cookie("anewsletter", "1", { expires: 7 });
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
        $.cookie("anewsletter", "1", { expires: 7 });
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
            $.cookie("anewsletter", "1", { expires: 7 });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```